# Extjs Stacked Bar Chart Numeric Axes schould be lazy

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

I've got a problem with my bar chart. I am displaying a bar chart that should behave like a Percentage bar chart. It all works fine, except the fact, that when my Percentage value is at 55 %, the x axes goes till 60%. It dynamically resizes, however, I want it always to stay at 100.

heres my code

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['process', 'identifikation', 'beurteilung', 'training', 'zusage', 'gewonnen'],
    data: [
        { process: 'Prozess', identifikation: 10, beurteilung: 20, training: 20, zusage: 0, gewonnen: 0 }
    ]
});

var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    theme: 'Browser:gradients',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    store: store,
    legend: {
        position: 'top'
    },
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['identifikation', 'beurteilung', 'training', 'zusage', 'gewonnen'],
        title: true,
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['process'],
        title: true
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        axis: 'bottom',
        gutter: 80,
        xField: 'process',
        yField: ['identifikation', 'beurteilung', 'training', 'zusage', 'gewonnen'],
        stacked: true
    }]
});
```

I hope someone can show me a way, how to set the size of the xaxis

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can set minimum and maximum to your Numeric axis, which will force the axis to these values.

```
var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
width: 500,
height: 200,
theme: 'Browser:gradients',
animate: true,
shadow: true,
store: store,
legend: {
    position: 'top'
},
axes: [{
    type: 'Numeric',
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 100, //You need to change this values dynamically if you percentages are more than 100, as with this field it restricts to 100 
    position: 'bottom',
    fields: ['identifikation', 'beurteilung', 'training', 'zusage', 'gewonnen'],
    title: true,
}, {
    type: 'Category',
    position: 'left',
    fields: ['process'],
    title: true
}],
series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    axis: 'bottom',
    gutter: 80,
    xField: 'process',
    yField: ['identifikation', 'beurteilung', 'training', 'zusage', 'gewonnen'],
    stacked: true
}]
});
```

Comment: how do i change the value of maximum dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a 100% stacked bar just change "stacked: true" for "fullStack: true".